# UITextView - some fonts cause text to disappear

Tags: ios, uitextview, uifont

I'm having an interesting problem with `UITextView`. I use this code to put a text view on the screen in `loadView` of a view controller:

```
self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
if (self.tutorialPage.text.length > 0)
{
    self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.textView.editable = NO;
    self.textView.text = self.tutorialPage.text;
    self.textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    self.textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    //Later constraints are added
}

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Bold" size:(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? 20.0 : 15.0)];
self.textView.font = font;
[self.view addSubview:self.textView];
```

Every line of this code gets called, by the way, and the text view is definitely onscreen. But somehow, when this same code is called again to create another view controller of the same type, the text doesn't show up. When I select text in the text view by tapping and holding, though, the text suddenly appears.

Even weirder, when I change this line

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Bold" size:(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? 20.0 : 15.0)];
```

to use a different font name, such as `@"Noteworthy-Light"`, or `@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT"`, the text view behaves as expected... What could be the cause of this problem?

Has anyone ever seen this problem before? If so, please share how you solved it or worked around it.

Comment: Use it in viewDidload

Comment: @iT. Tried moving all the view-loading code into viewDidLoad except for the part that allocates the view, but no luck. I'm not using IB for this view controller, so loadView is where I create all my subviews and add constraints.

Comment: Sometimes, the OS that you are using, or the type of font itself only works for certain things. It can be weird because it varies on what font you are actually using. Even if you used a common font such as Georgia. That would behave differently than say using AppleGothic

Comment: Turns out, if I change the *width* of the text view from 688 to around 512, the text stays there. I've tested out Noteworthy Bold, Light and Helvetica Bold and Regular, and they all seem to work at around 510-520. But my question is, why on earth does it matter to the text view?

Comment: Is it wrapping? Can you only see one line of the UITextView and the larger fonts are wrapping and inserting a new line and bumping the text out of the frame?

Comment: @Randy Well, my text is around four or five lines at 512 px width, and it was either all the text showed or none did. And if it didn't show, selecting text caused it to appear all at once. But since it's a non-editable text view, I didn't want the user to have to tap it at all. So it works now, I'm just curious as to why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by firstly setting the UIFont and afterwards setting the UIColour+NSTextAlignment. Briefly told,you have to set: font -> colours/other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make that text field first responder than make it in viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear. Your problem will solve.